# Which tense of main verb follows "could" and "would"?

Tags: indian-english

I am really confused with the following sentences.

> • I could do my work earlier.
>   • I could did my work earlier.

And

> •I would do exercise if I was in your place.
>   •I would did exercise if I was in your place.

From both, which one is correct?
And if both are correct, then what's the difference between them?
Please answer timely because I am having the exam of English grammar tomorrow.

Comment: We only inflect ***one*** element of a "multi-word composite verb" form, and that's already been done with the "auxiliaries" ***would, could***. So any "main" verb must simply be left in the ***infinitive*** form ***do*** ("unmarked"; we don't include the infinitive marker ***to***).

Comment: _Did_, like all past tense forms (and like all modal auxiliaries), can only occur as the first verb in a verb phrase. Only that first verb can have tense; all following verbs in a verb chain are untensed infinitives or participles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These

> can could shall should will would may might must

are followed by the infintive form of the verb.

The book can **be** read.  "be" is the infinitive form, we do not say "is" or "are" or "was" or "were" here.

I could **do** my work.  "do" is the infinitive form, we do not say "does" or "did" or "done" here.

I could not **do** the work last week but I can **do** the work this week.